# What's command line to compile 2 files into a single exe that uses the math.h library in C

Tags: c, bash, gcc

Thanks for the help. I've tried a couple of things and can't seem to get it to compile. Say you have two files, say, program1.c and program2.c and you want to compile them into a single executable called run and you need to include the math.h library. I'm using Ubuntu LTS. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc program1.c program2.c -lm -o yourProgram` is the command. You might want `sudo` if you don't have necessary permissions.

Comment: Only something as brain-dead as Ubuntu could require root to compile code :-) But +1 since your command line is right.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I left off the -o. Thank you so much. -court

Comment: Is Ubuntu not good? What's a good version of Unix that's free to use?

Comment: Almost every other linux is free to use @court. Try others, debian and fedora are my favorites, but you can try many. See here: distrowatch.com

Comment: Thanks! I have to use a version of Unix (or linux obviously) for classes here at Clemson and I just chose Ubuntu because I had heard people talking about it. You guys are awesome. Thanks seriously.

Answer (score 1):

math.h is a (standard) header file, not a library. A header file contains the declarations and prototypes necessary for using features of a library. A library contains the actual object code. To compile your program, try:

gcc program1.c program2.c -o myprog

It's also  possible you might have to add -lm to link to the math library.